# Access Javascript variable inside of an Apex:repeat

Tags: apex, javascript, google-map

I am currently trying to add some customer markers to a map. I can add a single marker to the map but when I move that same logic inside of an Apex:repeat I no longer have access to the map variable.

My Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function initialize() {
      var mapProp = {
        center:new google.maps.LatLng(52.634092,-0.148315),
        zoom:10,
        mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };         
        var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);       
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

My VP page:

```
   <apex:repeat value="{!Locations}" var="local" id="mapMarkers" >
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var lat = '{!Locations[0].Geolocation__Latitude__s}';
        var lng = '{!Locations[0].Geolocation__Longitude__s}';
        var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng)   

        });          
        marker.setMap(map); 
    </script>
</apex:repeat>
```

The !Locations list is in my controller and just pulls the latitude and longitude from my Tree__c object:

```
   public List<Tree__c> getLocations() {
    List<Tree__c> locations = Database.query('SELECT Geolocation__Latitude__s, Geolocation__Longitude__s FROM Tree__c WHERE Geolocation__Latitude__s !=null AND Geolocation__Longitude__s !=null ');
    return locations;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you are using your apex:repeat is not correct.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //rest of your javascript...
    <apex:repeat value="{!Locations}" var="local">
        var lat = '{!local.Geolocation__Latitude__s}';
        var lng = '{!local.Geolocation__Longitude__s}';
        var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng)   

        });          
        marker.setMap(map); 
    </apex:repeat>
</script>
```

Comment: quite annoyed I didn't spot that! Thanks for the help :)